# Diff in Diff with fading treatment impact

Tags: python, difference-in-difference, ab-test

I am interested in running a diff in diff model to measure the impact of stock count(the treatment) on sales in a number of supermarkets.

After a stock take, the inaccuracies in stock take will grow by an unknown amount, and this is likely to impact sales as certain products will be underordered and go out of stock more regularly than the system recognises.

If I run a diff in diff model, should I include a binary feature for the treatment, and then a continuous variable for t from treatment?

I also am assuming that since the model will include a fixed effect, it is not necessary for me to include any other independent variables (distance to competitors, land density, shop size etc.). If this assumption is wrong please correct me.

Finally I week cluster the errors of the fixed effect around time and store location.

Comment: In short, you want to model the change in stock count both discretely *and* continuously?

Comment: Sorry bad explaining on my part. The stocktake is the treatment